# insert bash-variables in psql-command

Tags: bash, postgresql, variables, parameters, psql

I'm going crazy while trying to insert bash-variables in a psql commands as connection paramters as well as variables in the command itself. The following example works properly:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -c "CREATE DATABASE  testdb WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=postgres TABLESPACE=pg_default TEMPLATE=template_postgis CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;"
```

Now I'm trying to exchange each parameter through a variable, which is held in special config-file.

Non-working example:

```
dbserver=localhost
dbport=5432
dbowner=postgres
dbname=testdb
dbtemplate=template_postgis
dbtablespace=pg_default

 psql -U '$dbowner' -h '$dbserver' -p '$dbport' -c "CREATE DATABASE  '$dbname' WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER='§dbowner' TABLESPACE='$dbtablespace' TEMPLATE='$dbtemplate'
CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;"
```

I've tried several quotings, backquotes and escape-slashes already but smhow it still won't work.
Thanks in advance, knutella

Comment: And the error you get is...

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes ("). Single quotes (') does not interpret shell variables inside.

Try it

```
 echo '$USER' "$USER"
```

See `man bash`.

Comment: Thanks, this also this works fine for me now. As I wrote in above's comments: ...my variables were sourced in incorrectly and empty..

Answer (score 3):

This works... most of the quotes are not needed:

```
 psql -U $dbowner -h $dbserver -p $dbport -c "CREATE DATABASE  $dbname WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=$dbowner TABLESPACE=$dbtablespace TEMPLATE=$dbtemplate CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;"
```

Comment: Thanks this does the trick now. actually i tried it in the very first already, but problem was, that paramters are smhow where not proberly sourced in from config-file.